# AWS unencrypted disk reuse: Security

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, encryption, amazon-ec2

AWS (or any other public cloud provider) is a public cloud, which also provides HDDs for their EC2 service. These disks can be either encrypted (user level) or unencrypted.

Consider you are using an unencrypted HDD (but store there sensite data), you deprovision the EC2 instance. AWS then probably somehow wipes the FS and mounts the disk to the next customer.

My question is simple: how does the wiping out works? Is it just logical wiping on AWS OS level (without some table, you will get zeroes). Is the disk just overwritten once with zeroes? Or are the data by default encrypted (and the encryption is totally transparent)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Security of the solution was in my eyes always part of the development. Also how big players are solving this type of multitenancy is also a development question. Yes, it may be also interesting on SU, but probably not on WM (its not even web related...). IS is mainly about crypto itself (while accoring to the answer to this question, this is not about crypto at all...). Regarding topic: I see this between "tools" and "problem unique to sw development"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS comply to many industry standards, so they maintain high level of security when de-provisioning instances. You can find more information what happens when cleaning the space in the [Overview of Security Processes](https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/overview-of-security-processes/).

quoting form whitepaper

> Customer instances have no access to raw disk devices, but instead are
>   presented with virtualized disks. The AWS proprietary disk virtualization layer
>   automatically resets every block of storage used by the customer, so that one
>   customer’s data is never unintentionally exposed to another. In addition,
>   memory allocated to guests is scrubbed (set to zero) by the hypervisor when it is
>   unallocated to a guest. The memory is not returned to the pool of free memory
>   available for new allocations until the memory scrubbing is complete.